# Can't detect the socket is disconnected

Tags: java, android, sockets

Hi this is my code for sending data through a socket to another device connected to the network

```
try {
     PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
     printWriter.print(data);
     Log.d("error", printWriter.checkError() + "");
     printWriter.flush();
} catch (IOException e) {
     Log.d("socket","is disconnected");
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

the problem is `printWriter.checkError()` is always returning `false` and the `IOException` never happens. for disconnecting socket I'm turning device off and trying to send data again. even reading from `InputStream` doesn't help

```
private class SocketHandler extends AsyncTask<Void, byte[], Void> {
    InputStream in;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        try {
            in = socket.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        byte[] content = new byte[2048];
        if (in != null) {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    if (in.available() > 0) {
                        int n = in.read(content);
                        if (n == -1) {
                            break;
                        }
                        publishProgress(new byte[][]{Arrays.copyOfRange(content, 0, n)});
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(byte[]... values) {
        String data = new String(values[0]);
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        Log.d("socket", "is disconnected");
    }
}
```

`read` never returns `-1` so I can detect the socket is disconnected. What can I do?

edit: It's not duplicate of [JAVA : Handling socket disconnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12243765/java-handling-socket-disconnection) because I did everything mentioned there

Comment: 'I did everything mentioned there': no you didn't. I mentioned there, and here, 'you should use a read timeout.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. I used a timer to send **connection check** command every second in both side and in that timer I checked the last time that I received this **connection check** command and if it's over for example 10 seconds, then I decided that the socket is disconnected

```
tOut = new Timer();
tOut.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        long dif = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastCCReceivedTime;
        if (dif > 1000 * 10) {
            // socket is disconnected
            return;
        }


        try {
            out.println("Connection check");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (out != null)
                out.close();

            // socket is disconnected
        }
    }
}, 1000, 1000);
```

Save the last time that the command was received

```
while ((msg = in.readLine()) != null) {
    lastCCReceivedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    //Message received
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (in.available() > 0) {
```

You never call `read()` unless there is data available to be read without blocking.

```
                    int n = in.read(content);
                    if (n == -1) {
                        break;
```

Unreachable.

```
                }
```

And here if `available()` was zero you do nothing except spin mindlessly smoking the CPU.

Cure: remove the `available()` test. It isn't doing anything useful, and it is preventing you from detecting end of stream.

Comment: I removed that but it's not working

Comment: Then the peer isn't closing the connection.

Comment: no it's not because I'm turning it off. in this case I can't detect it's disconnected?

Comment: Not unless you set a read timeout.